# UIViewController instance issue

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I am trying to set a NSUserDefaults variable on a separate swift file (Login.swift) to determine if my user is logged in. If the user is indeed logged in, the LoginViewController will disappear and the HomeViewController will be shown. However I am being thrown this error

> Use of instance member 'dismissViewControllerAnimated' on type 'UIViewController'; did you mean to use a value of type 'UIViewController' instead?

This is my code

```
//success
else if value["username"] != nil && value["password"] == nil && value["message"] == nil
{
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")

 LoginViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)

 if let api_key = value["api_token"].string
 {
    print("The token is " + api_key)
 }
 else
 {
    print("error parsing api token")
 }
 //pass data to Users class
 _ = Users.init(Name: value["name"].string, Email: value["email"].string, Id: value["id"].int, ProfilePicture: value["profile_picture"].string, Username: value["username"].string)
 }
```

[image: UIViewController error]

Comment: dismissViewControllerAnimated is and object method, why you calling it using class name..?

Answer (score 0):

`dismissViewControllerAnimated` Its `Instance` method not `class` method. Its looks like you are calling with class.

If you are on same controller use:

```
[topVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

or

If you are not in that controller use

```
 UIViewController *topVC =  [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController;
 [topVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the object of LoginViewController.
Using that object then call dismissViewControllerAnimated function.
Direct calling from class name is not allowed